# Handling a keyboard event in one place for the whole program

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm creating a little developer console for an AS3 AIR application, I'm wanting F12 to add the toggle the display of the console screen but I don't want to litter my program with a bunch of calls to the Console to show or hide it, I also don't really want to be re-creating the console on different screens of my application.

I'm wondering if there's a way or a place I can put my keyboard event to toggle the display that will handle it across the entire application? At the moment I've tried putting it into my Main class which calls the first screen in the hopes that would be able to handle it but as soon as I click on another screen my eventListener isn't called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Woops, I'm not quite with it today!

For future reference I added the event listener to the Stage in my Main function and it's being picked up every time.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, toggleDevConsole, false, 0, true);
```

Comment: This will only work when the window whose stage your referencing has the focus.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your event listener to [`FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html#topLevelApplication) instead of specific views, this would achieve the reduction you require

Comment: Good idea, I've sorted it with a similar solution of adding the event listener to the stage in my Main function which seems to be working as desired. Thanks

Comment: No problem glad you found a solution

Answer (score 1):

For true application level keyboard handling,  attach the listener on the `NativeApplication.nativeApplication` object.

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, toggleDevConsole,false,0,true);
```

Attaching the listener to the stage will only work when that particular stage (window) has the focus. This will become an issue if your application has multiple windows that require interaction.

For single window applications, either will work.